# How do I make a data within a view refresh when initiated?

Tags: swift, swiftui, healthkit

I have a capsule with the number of steps displayed inside. This capsule is in my Home View which is one of the tabs in the tab bar. This is what is meant by a step capsule:

[image]

When I use onAppear and initialise the view for the second time, the steps capsule view loads again but the previous one is still there (so there are two step capsule views).

I don't want a second capsule view. I want the data in the first step capsule to change.

To stop the second capsule view I switched onAppear to onLoad this (it was successful):

```
struct ViewDidLoadModifier: ViewModifier {

    @State private var didLoad = false
    private let action: (() -> Void)?

    init(perform action: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.action = action
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.onAppear {
            if didLoad == false {
                didLoad = true
                action?()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {

    func onLoad(perform action: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> some View {
        modifier(ViewDidLoadModifier(perform: action))
    }

}
```

This is the onLoad function in use (replaced onAppear):

```
 .onLoad {
            if let healthStore = healthStore {
                healthStore.requestAuthorization { success in
                    if success {
                        healthStore.calculateSteps { statisticsCollection in
                            if let statisticsCollection = statisticsCollection {
                                // update the UI
                                updateUIFromStatistics(statisticsCollection)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This fixed the a new step capsule appearing every time the view was initiated however the data doesn't change. When the user takes more steps and goes onto the home view, I want to run the function that fetches the step data again.

How do I get the step data in the capsule to refresh when the view is initiated?

Comment: You can make an observable view model to hold the number of step. The view will update as the number changes.

Comment: I see, how would I do this?